# is there a way to query HBA ports state in Windows Server?

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows-server, get-wmiobject

I am using WMI Classes to query all kinds of information from servers. The reason I am using WMI Objects is because I work with versions of Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2022 (PS 1.0 to 5.X). But now I need to query FC ports in multiple physical servers.

I have tried the following classes which return some useful properties but none about the operating status of the FC ports:

```
root\CIMV2: Win32_SCSIController
root\WMI: MSFC_FibrePortHBAStatistics
root\WMI: MSFC_FibrePortHBAAttributes
root\WMI: MSFC_HBAPortAttributesResults
root\WMI: MSFC_FCAdapterHBAAttributes
root\WMI: MSFC_HBAFCPInfo
root\WMI: MSFC_HBAPortStatistics
```

What I need is very simple which is basically counting the total of FC ports and then indicate many of those are active ports. Lets say I have 4 FC ports and only 2 are connected and linking so my output should be something like this:

```
Number of FC ports: 4
Number of used FC ports: 2
```

Unfortunately, the closest operational indication I was able to get was [HBA_STATUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/hba-status) and [Active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/msfc-fcadapterhbaattributes-wmi-class) properties which my guess is it only indicates administrative status. As a test I tried installing [Fiber Channel Information Tool (fcinfo)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17530) and I get this output which is great and exactly what I need but installing the software is not an option:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> fcinfo.exe /ports


                    com.qlogic-QLE2692-0, num: 1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Type     State   Speed             WWN                     PortWWN       |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Unknown, linkdown,  unkn,  20:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:2c,  21:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:2c


                    com.qlogic-QLE2692-1, num: 1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Type     State   Speed             WWN                     PortWWN       |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Unknown, linkdown,  unkn,  20:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:2d,  21:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:2d


                    com.qlogic-QLE2692-2, num: 1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Type     State   Speed             WWN                     PortWWN       |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Unknown, linkdown,  unkn,  20:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:6e,  21:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:6e


                    com.qlogic-QLE2692-3, num: 1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Type     State   Speed             WWN                     PortWWN       |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Unknown, linkdown,  unkn,  20:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:6f,  21:00:34:80:0d:f2:8c:6f
```

Any other way to query the state of the HBA ports and could work in as many as possible PS Versions is welcomed, but then again installing *FCInfo* is not an option.